# Removing frames with no motion in openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a openCV program where i am breaking down the video into frames and comparing two frames one after the other if both are the same i reject the frame else append the frame to a output file.

How can i achieve it?

OpenCV 2.4.13 Python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example captures frames from the first camera connected to your system, compares each frame to the previous frame, and when different, the frame is added to a file.  If you sit still in front of the camera, you might see the diagnostic 'no change' message printed if you run the program from a console terminal window.

There are a number of ways to measure how different one frame is from another.  For simplicity we have used the average difference, pixel by pixel, between the new frame and the previous frame, compared to a threshold.

Note that frames are returned as numpy arrays by the openCV read function.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

interval = 100
fps = 1000./interval
camnum = 0
outfilename = 'temp.avi'

threshold=100.

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camnum)

ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, nchannels = frame.shape

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter( outfilename,fourcc, fps, (width,height))

while(True):

    # previous frame
    frame0 = frame

    # new frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # how different is it?
    if np.sum( np.absolute(frame-frame0) )/np.size(frame) > threshold:
        out.write( frame )
    else:
        print( 'no change' )

    # show it
    cv2.imshow('Type "q" to close',frame)

    # check for keystroke
    key = cv2.waitKey(interval) & 0xFF

    # exit if so-commanded
    if key == ord('q'):
        print('received key q' )
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
out.release()
print('VideoDemo - exit' )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. but as a Noob question what does `interval = 100
fps = 1000./interval` do/ stand for?

Comment: The call to waitKey() takes a timeout parameter (interval), specified as an interval in number of milliseconds.  The call to VideoWrite() takes a frame rate, specified as frames per second (fps).   Normally you would have some sort of timing control in a loop to read and write video frames.  Here that is provided in an approximate way by the timeout in waitKey(), the actual frame rate is a little less than 1000/interval. But it is close enough for purposes of illustration.

Comment: So it is to allow efficient read and write of video. If i'm understanding properly.

Comment: OpenCV should be taking care of the efficiency of reading and writing the video. Non-blocking reads and writes might save some time in the loop, though that is not strictly the same thing as efficiency.  One way to do that would be to use three threads and two queues. One thread reads and engueues frames to the second thread, which compares images and enqueues accepted frame to the third thread, which writes them to disk.  This would clean up timing as well, since you would only need to accurately time the read loop.

Comment: @DrM how did you choose the threshold `100`?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is often, to set it empirically.   In principle you can estimate what this should be if you can estimate the typical variation within images that should not be considered different.  To do that you will have collected enough frames that you can set it by simply seeing what seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

using ffmpeg is faster than python:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vf "mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" "output.mp4"
```